# Route-specific ASP.NET MVC Web API message handler not invoking controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, message-handlers

I've got an ASP.NET MVC Web API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage req, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {...}
```

And a custom message handler I created:

```
public class MyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
     protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         // ...

         var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

         // ...

        return response;
      }
  }
```

And in `WebConfigApi.cs` I wire up the message handler route-specific to the controller action method:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "UpdateStuffAPI",
   routeTemplate: "api/updatestuff/post/{stuffid}",
   defaults: new { feedid = RouteParameter.Optional },
   constraints: null,
   handler: new MyMessageHandler()
);
```

When I POST to the controller action method, e.g.:

`http://hostname/api/updatestuff/post?stuffid=12345`

The message handler intercepts the request as expected.  But in stepping through the line:

`var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);`

the controller action method is never hit.

As a test I removed the route-specific wiring and made the message handler global:

`configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyMessageHandler());`

and `SendAsync` properly invokes my controller's action method.

So my thought was that something is wrong with the route definition.  However, the message handler *is* invoked with the route-specific wiring, *and*, [Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) shows that when I POST to my controller (`http://hostname/api/updatestuff/post?stuffid=12345`), that that route *is* being used.

Why isn't my action method being invoked when I wire up the message handler in a route-specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the code that ties the message handler back to the route/controller it should invoke next.

Route-specific message handlers must be specifically told about the Web Api application's `HttpConfiguration`.  What I had in `WebConfigApi.cs` was:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "UpdateStuffAPI",
   routeTemplate: "api/updatestuff/post/{stuffid}",
   defaults: new { feedid = RouteParameter.Optional },
   constraints: null,
   handler: new MyMessageHandler()
);
```

What I needed to was:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "UpdateStuffAPI",
   routeTemplate: "api/updatestuff/post/{stuffid}",
   defaults: new { feedid = RouteParameter.Optional },
   constraints: null,
   handler: new MyMessageHandler(configuration)
);
```

In other words, the configuration object needed to be passed to the message handler upon construction.  So the message handler needs a constructor:

```
public MyMessageHandler(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
{
   InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(httpConfiguration);
}
```

I naively assumed that setting `handler: new MyMessageHandler()` in the route map was enough to tie the message handler back to the controller(s) that the route maps to.

While this is resolved, I admittedly don't yet understand why this is required (why my assumption was incorrect) so I'm going to read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling attribute routing using:

configuration.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

Routing is also dependent on order in which you map attribute route and normal http route.

Comment: I was using attribute routing at one point but specifying the message handler still must be done and for that I believe a route map definition is required.